# Can I ask "Professional Careers and Advice" questions here?

Tags: discussion, questions

I created [Professional Careers and Advice](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/24003/professional-careers-advice) at Area 51. Then this proposal came along which I think is a superset of mine. I'd like to recommend people come here instead (I've already added an announcement).

But I would also like to test some of the questions from that proposal. Is that ok? I guess so but it is worth mentioning a few in case they are completely off topic. E.g.:

1. I enjoy creative problem solving, delivering quality solutions, presenting and coaching. I have an IT background. What jobs match this profile?
2. What is the pros and cons of Software Developers doing Management Courses?
3. In interviews my mind goes blank - I just freeze up. Does anyone have any tips for overcoming this?
4. What are your top three questions for interviewing candidates?
5. I live in [Toronto] and want to start work as a [software tester]. I have a batchelors in IT. What starting salary should I expect?

Are they all on topic?

(See also **[Merge Career Proposals](https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/613/merge-career-proposals)** and particularly the accepted answer.)

Comment: Possibly related: http://meta.workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/48/job-marketplace-vs-workplace.  I didn't see your question before writing mine.

Answer (score 2):

1 and 2: off-topic; this site doesn't do career advice.

3: on-topic (could be worded better) and I think has been asked but I haven't searched.

4: as written off-topic, but "what questions can I ask to evaluate $characteristic?" would be on-topic.

5: too localized, though "which salary surveys are most reliable" (or some such) might be on-topic.

Answer (score 1):

I can not see any of these questions flying on an actual SE Site.  They are Bad Subjective, and ask for lists, and look for information that is better found elsewhere on the internet.

Comment: If someone disagrees I urge them to speak up.. We need to define the community.

Comment: I'm not the source of your downvote, but I do think question #3 has some _possibility_ of being answerable.  It calls to mind [this answer](http://music.stackexchange.com/a/426/15) to a question asked in obviously a very different setting.  I agree that #2 and #4 call for lists and that #1 and #5 are just "reference" (i.e., Google it or use salary.com) questions.

Comment: @Andrew - I Debated that myself.  Personally I would not vote to close that one though I would not vote to reopen either if it did get closed.  I think it is pretty borderline.  Depending on how it was asked I could see it falling on either side.  1 and 5 are off topic as well because as you said they are easily referenced elsewhere.

Comment: I downvoted, apologies for not explaining (I *hate* it when that happens :) ). I downvoted because the answer did not sufficiently (for me) explain why these questions would not fit. I expected more detail, possible per question. To take just the first question, what makes it **bad** subjective? Is it really a *list* question (seems like a pretty limited list to me)? Where could it be better found?

Comment: @Wikis Meta is different from the regular site.  Down votes mean you do not agree not that the answer is not good enough.  If you disagree or just want a better answer feel free to write it.  I have considered itemizing but doing so really sounds like beating up the OP with each version